# Makefile unable to compile file

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

Netbeans 7.3
gcc 4.5.3

I've looked at some of the answers to this question but I don't see my specific case.

The makefile generated by Netbeans seems to be correct. The output given in the Netbeans terminal window gives a `No rule to make target ReadList.cpp` , which seems to be wrong. I can't figure out what's going on.

The output window shows:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/SLIP/slip'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/slip.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/SLIP/slip'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `ReadList.cpp', needed by `build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/ReadList.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/SLIP/slip'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:94: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/SLIP/slip'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 375ms)
```

The makefile used shows:

```
${OBJECTDIR}/SlipReadList.o: SlipReadList.cpp 
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}
    ${RM} $@.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) -g -w -MMD -MP -MF $@.d -o ${OBJECTDIR}/SlipReadList.o SlipReadList.cpp
```

The makefile appears correct and works for other files. I have verified that the .cpp and .h files are in the same directory and are in the same directory as other successfully compiled files. Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Well the error says that the missing file is ReadList.cpp not SlipReadList.cpp

Comment: Well that helps. I don't have a ReadList.cpp (but I think you have solved my problem), sign and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `ReadList.cpp', needed by `build/Debug/Cygwin
```

now take a look at your make file:

```
${OBJECTDIR}/SlipReadList.o: SlipReadList.cpp
```

you have *readlist.cpp* initially, but the makefile wants a *SlipReadList.cpp*. Because of this the compiler has no idea what to do with *readlist.cpp*. A simple fix would be the change the naming of the file to SlipReadList.cpp